# Can I use 'since' or 'for' in other tenses?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Example:

> The company has been the duty-free operator in Kolkata **since** 2008.

Which is the correct way to say:

> The company is the duty-free operator in Kolkata since 2008

or

> I have seen many changes in Kolkata since 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ● The company has been the duty-free operator in Kolkata since 2008.
>
> ● I have seen many changes in Kolkata since 2008.

Both of these look correct to me. ***Since*** is generally used with perfect tenses. **For**, on the other hand, is used with both perfect and simple tenses.